# onBindViewHolder mess with pictures

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list for recycler view wtih person's cards. Each card must have 1 picture and name(pic 1, there are loading from json). But for most cards - have not corresponding pictures in json. And when i search for name, same photos are assigning for different names(pic 2).
Please help, how fix that?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CriticResults criticResults = results.get(position);
    holder.tvTitle.setText( criticResults.getDisplayName() );
    try {
         Picasso.get().load( criticResults.getMultimedia().getResource().getSrc() ).into( holder.ivPhoto );
    }
   catch (Exception o){}
}
```

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM6aK.jpg)
[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59L4o.png)

Comment: use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` instead of `position` in this line : `results.get(position);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `if-else` and `holder.getAdapterPosition()`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CriticResults criticResults = results.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    holder.tvTitle.setText( criticResults.getDisplayName() );

    if(criticResults.getMultimedia().getResource().getSrc() != null) {
        Picasso.get().load(criticResults.getMultimedia().getResource().getSrc()).into(holder.ivPhoto);
    } else {
    Picasso.get().load(/*Your default pic*/).into(holder.ivPhoto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not show us your view holder object but I guess your problem is you are not overwriting the `ImageView` content when there is no image to show, so the last loaded images is shown.

You should do something like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CriticResults criticResults = results.get(position);
    holder.tvTitle.setText( criticResults.getDisplayName());

    if (criticResults.getMultimedia().getResource().getSrc() != null) {
        Picasso.get().load(criticResults.getMultimedia().getResource().getSrc())
        .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
        .into(holder.ivPhoto)
    } else {
        holder.ivPhoto.setDrawable(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error);
    }
}
```

It's possible it works just with `error()` call on `Picasso`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help! It has worked(ifs don't - get error "null refference"):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CriticResults criticResults = critics.get(position);
    holder.tvTitle.setText( criticResults.getDisplayName() );
    try {
         Picasso.get().load( criticResults.getMultimedia().getResource().getSrc() ).into( holder.ivPhoto );
    }
   catch (Exception o){
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.noimage).into(holder.ivPhoto);
    }

}
```